# Android: workaround to not extend from 2 classes

Tags: android

I was programming a BaseActivity to add the same (common) menu to all my Activities. Then my goal was in all my Activities extends BaseActivity and I would have the same menu. The problem is that, for instance in MainActivity, I have an extends ActionBarActivity because I need to configure the ActionBar. 
Do you have any workaround to solve this issue since I can't extends 2 classes?

**BaseActivity.java**

```
 public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_common, menu);
            return true;
        }
    (...)
```

**IndexActivity.java**

```
public class IndexActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //show the icon of the application with Theme AppCompat
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"grey\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{


}
```

And

```
public class IndexActivity extends BaseActivity 
{

}
```

Your common code will be in your BaseActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can replace extension with delegation to solve such multi extensions problem in Java. But as PPD said, all your Activities can extend from `ActionBarActivity`.